# JavaFX .getItem() returns a song a but thinks its just an object

Tags: button, javafx, tablecolumn

Okay for some reason, when I want to do the following:

```
MusicPlayer.playlist.add(getTableRow().getItem() );
```

I get the following error

```
incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Song
                MusicPlayer.playlist.add(getTableRow().getItem() );
```

However when I do the following:

```
System.out.println("Button being pressed on: \n"+getTableRow().getItem().getClass());
```

My terminal outputs the following

```
Button being pressed on:
class Song
```

So i'm not sure why this isn't working, any ideas? What I have is a tableColumn of buttons that when pressed add a song who's row the button is in to a Playlist playlist. the issue is happening inside the handle method of the button class. So any solutions? thanks.

Comment: Can't you just downcast it?

Comment: haha how strange, I tried doing that yesterday and it didn't work, but i did it today and it did! thanks!

Comment: Hm... the question is answered but not recognizable as that. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Downcasted the returned object to song so that it ended up like this
(Song) getTableRow().getItem()

Thanks @James_D